# XSLT - replace "value" element. Condition replase "key"

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML with PII.

**Example XML:**

```
<DictionarySerializer>
  <dictionary xmlns="http://www.kmanage.com/xml/serialization">
    <item>
      <key>FirstName</key>
      <value>John</value>
      <type>String</type>
      <history>
        <value stamp="201405301854095003707" owner="admin" type="String">John</value>
      </history>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>FirstName</key>
      <value>John</value>
      <type>String</type>
      <history>
        <value stamp="201405301854095003707" owner="admin" type="String">John</value>
      </history>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>MiddleName</key>
      <value>quo</value>
      <type>String</type>
      <history>
        <value stamp="201405301854095003707" owner="admin" type="String">quo</value>
      </history>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>LastName</key>
      <value>Dou</value>
      <type>String</type>
      <history>
        <value stamp="201405301854095003707" owner="admin" type="String">Dou</value>
      </history>
    </item>
  </dictionary>
</DictionarySerializer>
```

I need transform "value" element. Condition replase "key"

**My XSLT for replace "value" of one "key":**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.kmanage.com/xml/serialization">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="doc:item[doc:key/text() = 'FirstName']/doc:value/text()">
   <xsl:text>********</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need replace "value" if "key" equal FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Passport and so on...

**My result:**

```
<DictionarySerializer>
  <dictionary xmlns="http://www.kmanage.com/xml/serialization">
    <item>
      <key>FirstName</key>
      <value>********</value>
      <type>String</type>
      <history>
        <value stamp="201405301854095003707" owner="admin" type="String">John</value>
      </history>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>FirstName</key>
      <value>********</value>
      <type>String</type>
      <history>
        <value stamp="201405301854095003707" owner="admin" type="String">John</value>
      </history>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>MiddleName</key>
      <value>quo</value>
      <type>String</type>
      <history>
        <value stamp="201405301854095003707" owner="admin" type="String">quo</value>
      </history>
    </item>
    <item>
      <key>LastName</key>
      <value>Dou</value>
      <type>String</type>
      <history>
        <value stamp="201405301854095003707" owner="admin" type="String">Dou</value>
      </history>
    </item>
  </dictionary>
</DictionarySerializer>
```

How can I do this without using an array?

Regards, Ilya

Comment: XSLT doesn't have the concept of an "array".  The best thing you can do is edit the question to show us what result XML you're trying to generate, and we can then suggest the best approach to achieve that.

Comment: It remains unclear to me what you need. Is it that you want to remove the `<value/>` if the `<key/>` matches one of a limited set of keys?

Comment: Do not remove. I want to replace/change the <value/> if the <key/> matches one of a limited set of keys. Set of keys also maybe changed. Therefore I would like to use an "array".
P.S.: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to treat all of keys equally you can use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:doc="http://www.kmanage.com/xml/serialization">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc:item[doc:key = 'FirstName' or doc:key = 'LastName' or doc:key = 'DateOfBirth' or doc:key = 'Passport' or doc:key = 'and so on...']/doc:value/text()">
    <xsl:text>********</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Though personally I prefer creating a lookup table for those things. You can use exslt for that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:doc="http://www.kmanage.com/xml/serialization"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="keysXml">
        <keys>
            <key>FirstName</key>
            <key>LastName</key>
            <key>DateOfBirth</key>
            <!-- add all required keys here -->
        </keys>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="keys" select="exsl:node-set($keysXml)/keys" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc:value">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$keys/key = ../doc:key">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:text>********</xsl:text>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This way all you need to do is add another entry for another key, which makes maintainability a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks. I use this transform with c#. **xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">** do not work.
As for me work **xmlns:exsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"**

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:doc="http://www.kmanage.com/xml/serialization">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="doc:item[doc:key/text() = 'FirstName']/doc:value/text()">
 <xsl:text>********</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="doc:item[doc:key/text() = 'LastName']/doc:value/text()">
 <xsl:text>******** lastName replacement</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I agree, it works. This is an example of a xml. Work xml contain more keys. Set of keys also maybe changed.

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet filters out the `value` of a `key` matching a list:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:doc="http://www.kmanage.com/xml/serialization" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="doc:value/text()">
    <xsl:variable name="associated-key" select="../preceding-sibling::doc:key/text()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$associated-key = 'FirstName' or $associated-key = 'LastName' or $associated-key = 'DateOfBirth'">********</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could wring out more elegance by storing the list of filtered keys in a variable and using XPath’s `contains` function to see whether the current key matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the list of PII keys inside of your stylesheet, then you could specify a delimited list of key names and test whether the value of the `doc:key` (with the delimiter concatenated as a prefix and suffix to avoid partial matches on key names) is contained within the list of delimited PII keys.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.kmanage.com/xml/serialization">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc:item[contains(
                                   '|FirstName|LastName|DateOfBirth|Passport|',
                                    concat('|', doc:key, '|') 
                                   )]/doc:value/text()">
        <xsl:text>********</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```